# AVAudioEngine not posting notification in SpriteKit

Tags: ios, notifications, avaudioengine

I have a problem with AVAudioEngine in SpriteKit game - when plugging/unplugging of headphones the engine stops and when the next sound play the app crashes. It is a known bug (or feature?) - with a suggestion to fix it - to use notification center, AVAudioEngine should post notification when it is changing it's states. I have made this code:

```
let notificationName = Notification.Name("AVAudioEngineConfigurationChange")      

NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.restartEngine(notification:)), name: notificationName, object: nil)
```

When I do this:

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: notificationName, object: nil)
```

My selector gets called. However when I plug/unplug headphones - nothing happens. Swift 3, xcode 8, iOS 9.3
Any suggestions on how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original Cocoa name of the notification is `AVAudioEngineConfigurationChangeNotification`, but the Swift constant is called `AVAudioEngineConfigurationChange`. Therefore you can handle the notification by using either:

```
let notificationName = Notification.Name("AVAudioEngineConfigurationChangeNotification")
```

or

```
let notificationName = Notification.Name.AVAudioEngineConfigurationChange
```

Your selector should then be called when plugging-in/unplugging headphones.

This appears to only be a partial solution for SpriteKit audio flakiness. I tried the following inside the notification handler:

```
try? self.audioEngine.start()
```

I was able to stop the crash, but my `SKAudioNode` wouldn't make any sound after the plug/unplug event, until the process was restarted.